# Simple Regex search does not work in my script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, gmail

I have these information in the email from which I want to extract the phone number:

```
Numéro de réservation:  254207287398084
Téléphone (portable):   0782375426
```

When I try finding `0782375426` with Regex, it works perfectly well on regex101.com with that regular expression: `/0[67][0-9]{8}\b`

However, this part of my script returns `null`:

```
var msg = messages[j].getBody();
    var search = "0[67][0-9]{8}\b";
    var regx = new RegExp("(.)"+search+"(.)");
var y = regx.exec(msg);
Logger.log(y);
```

Would you know what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check the value of msg

```
console.log(msg);
```

If it contains some html then try

```
var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
```

But I would use a simplier regex.  I used String.trim() because I get the blank space before the phone number also.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let msg = "Numéro de réservation:  254207287398084<br>Téléphone (portable):   0782375426<br>more";

    let find = msg.match(/\s0[67]\d+/);
    console.log(find[0].trim())
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

1:58:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:58:30 PM  Info    0782375426
1:58:29 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"0[67][0-9]{8}\b"` by `"0[67][0-9]{8}\\b"` and `"(.)"+search+"(.)"` by `search`

PS. The regular expression used in your script is '(.)0[67][0-9]{8}\b(.)`, not the one that you have tested in regex101.com.

```js
const msg = 
`
Numéro de réservation:  254207287398084
Téléphone (portable):   0782375426
`;
var search = "0[67][0-9]{8}\\b";
var regx = new RegExp(search);
var y = regx.exec(msg);
console.log(y)
```